# Extracting data from BeautifulSoup result set

Tags: beautifulsoup, resultset

I filtered this tag 

with 
data = soup.findAll('div',{'id':'responseDiv'})
and got this.

{"valid":"true","isinCode":null,"lastUpdateTime":"29-DEC-2016 12:19:23","ocLink":"/marketinfo/sym_map/symbolMapping.jsp?symbol=NIFTY&instrument=-&date=-&segmentLink=17&symbolCount=2","tradedDate":"29DEC2016","data":[{"change":"18.65","sellPrice1":"8,050.90","buyQuantity3":"75","sellPrice2":"8,050.95","buyQuantity4":"225","buyQuantity1":"750","ltp":"-","buyQuantity2":"150","sellPrice5":"8,051.15","sellPrice3":"8,051.00","buyQuantity5":"675","sellPrice4":"8,051.05","underlying":"NIFTY","bestSell":"-","annualisedVolatility":"16.61","optionType":"-","prevClose":"8,031.35","pChange":"0.23","lastPrice":"8,050.00","lowPrice":"8,025.00","strikePrice":"-","premiumTurnover":"-","numberOfContractsTraded":"54,112","underlyingValue":"8,055.20","openInterest":"1,03,46,700","impliedVolatility":"-",**"vwap":"8,046.98"**,"totalBuyQuantity":"5,20,350","openPrice":"8,028.00","closePrice":"0.00","bestBuy":"-","changeinOpenInterest":"-2,11,050","clientWisePositionLimits":"29320076","totalSellQuantity":"9,75,675","dailyVolatility":"0.87","sellQuantity5":"225","marketLot":"75","expiryDate":"29DEC2016","marketWidePositionLimits":"-","sellQuantity2":"150","sellQuantity1":"75","buyPrice1":"8,050.00","sellQuantity4":"150","buyPrice2":"8,049.80","sellQuantity3":"450","buyPrice4":"8,049.30","buyPrice3":"8,049.35","buyPrice5":"8,049.15","turnoverinRsLakhs":"3,26,578.64","pchangeinOpenInterest":"-2.00","settlementPrice":"8031.35","instrumentType":"FUTIDX","highPrice":"8,060.00"}],"companyName":"Nifty 50","eqLink":""}

]

I want to extract the text in bold. I just converted the whole thing to string and called by index. I am sure there is a proper way to convert resultset

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit unclear and needs editing, but that response looks like json. You can load it with

```
import json

...
data = soup.findAll('div',{'id':'responseDiv'})
```

And assuming what you really get from `findAll` is a list with elements that contain that json-text.

```
extracted = json.loads(data[0].getText())
print(extracted['data'][0]['vwap'])
```

> 8,046.98

The 'vwap' you are trying to extract can be accessed for example like that. The `extracted` is a dictionary that has a list with the key `'data'`, the 0th element of that list is a dictionary, and inside that with the keyword `'vwap'` is the information.